# Equivalent WPF binding syntax

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I need some help with WPF binding syntax:

```
public class ApplicationPresenter
{
    public ObservableCollection<Quotes> PriceList {get;}
}


public class WebSitePricesView
{
    private IApplicationPresenter presenter
    {
        get { return (ApplicationPresenter)DataContext; }
    }   

//  public ObservableCollection<Quotes> PriceList
//  {
//      get {return presenter.PriceList; }
    }
}
```

This XAML works fine:

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ApplicationPresenterDS" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ApplicationPresenter}" />
    <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="price_list" Source="{Binding Path=PriceList} />
</UserControl.Resources>                   
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource price_list}} />
```

However I don't want WebSitePricesView to expose PriceList, I want to bind the DataGridCollectionViewSource directly to ApplicationPresenter.PriceList.

This XAML doesn't bind any values to the grid. Obviously I'm doing something wrong in defining the Binding Source for price_list .....

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ApplicationPresenterDS" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ApplicationPresenter}" />
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="price_list" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationPresenterDS}, Path=PriceList />            
</UserControl.Resources>  
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource price_list}} />
```

The debug output for the first successful binding is:

```
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'Fenix.App.App'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 52 : Created BindingExpression (hash=35059110) for Binding (hash=15586314)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 :   Path: 'PriceList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Attach to Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewSource.Source (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Use Framework mentor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 91 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Got InheritanceContextChanged event from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Found data context element: WebSitePricesXc (hash=11090012) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 52 : Created BindingExpression (hash=53154844) for Binding (hash=52037308)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Attach to Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridControl.ItemsSource (hash=16991442)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Replace item at level 0 with <null>, using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): GetValue at level 0 from <null> using <null>: <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - using final value <null>
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Found data context element: WebSitePricesXc (hash=11090012) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Activate with root item ApplicationPresenter (hash=22260412)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110):   At level 0 - for ApplicationPresenter.PriceList found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Replace item at level 0 with ApplicationPresenter (hash=22260412), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): GetValue at level 0 from ApplicationPresenter (hash=22260412) using RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=40261689 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - got raw value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=40261689 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - using final value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=40261689 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 92 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Got PropertyChanged event from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373) for View
System.Windows.Data Warning: 75 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Activate with root item DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Replace item at level 0 with DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0), using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): GetValue at level 0 from DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0) using <null>: DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - got raw value DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - using final value DataGridCollectionView (hash=22444475 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 91 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Got PropertyChanged event from ApplicationPresenter (hash=22260412)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): GetValue at level 0 from ApplicationPresenter (hash=22260412) using RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=6408547 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - got raw value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=6408547 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - using final value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=6408547 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 92 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Got PropertyChanged event from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373) for View
System.Windows.Data Warning: 75 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Activate with root item DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): Replace item at level 0 with DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27), using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): GetValue at level 0 from DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27) using <null>: DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - got raw value DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=53154844): TransferValue - using final value DataGridCollectionView (hash=61423861 Count=27)
```

The debug output for the second binding is:

```
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'Fenix.App.App'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 52 : Created BindingExpression (hash=35059110) for Binding (hash=15586314)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 :   Path: 'PriceList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Attach to Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewSource.Source (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 73 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Use Data from ObjectDataProvider (hash=61302538)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Activate with root item ApplicationPresenter (hash=20390146)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110):   At level 0 - for ApplicationPresenter.PriceList found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): Replace item at level 0 with ApplicationPresenter (hash=20390146), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): GetValue at level 0 from ApplicationPresenter (hash=20390146) using RuntimePropertyInfo(PriceList): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=12781633 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - got raw value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=12781633 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=35059110): TransferValue - using final value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=12781633 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 52 : Created BindingExpression (hash=12661120) for Binding (hash=31408037)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Attach to Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridControl.ItemsSource (hash=16991442)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 72 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=28137373)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Activate with root item DataGridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): Replace item at level 0 with DataGridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0), using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 97 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): GetValue at level 0 from DataGridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0) using <null>: Data``GridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): TransferValue - got raw value DataGridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 85 : BindingExpression (hash=12661120): TransferValue - using final value DataGridCollectionView (hash=49343907 Count=0)
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is, the bindings (apart from the missing end quotes) appear to be fine. The following code works fine for me.

```
public class Quotes
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationPresenter
{
    public ApplicationPresenter()
    {
        PriceList = new ObservableCollection<Quotes>()
        {
            new Quotes(){Description="Quote One", Value=10m},
            new Quotes(){Description="Quote Two", Value=10m},
            new Quotes(){Description="Quote Three", Value=10m},
            new Quotes(){Description="Quote Four", Value=10m},
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Quotes> PriceList { get; private set; }
}

<Window 
    x:Class="ObjectDataProviderPresenterSample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObjectDataProviderPresenterSample"
    Title="Window1" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300" 
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider 
            x:Key="ApplicationPresenterDS" 
            ObjectType="{x:Type local:ApplicationPresenter}" 
            />
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource 
            x:Key="price_list" 
            Source="{Binding 
                        Source={StaticResource ApplicationPresenterDS}, 
                        Path=PriceList}" 
            />            
    </Window.Resources>  

    <Grid>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource price_list}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, since it is not very clear from your code where data go to PriceList, but what I see is that this collection is just empty in second xaml.

Creating ObjectDataProvider in xaml in both cases just creates object of type ApplicationPresenter through default constructor. Your constructor creates empty collection PriceList. (Ian's constructor creates PriceList AND fills it with fake data. That's why his example works).

So, DataGridCollectionViewSource in second xaml of your example basically refers to  ApplicationPresenter with empty PriceList.

The first xaml, in contrast, refers to PriceList of WebSitePricesView which, I believe, somehow is filled somewehere outside given slice of code.

If my theory is good, the removal of ObjectDataProvider from the first xaml won't cange anything - it sill will be working, because data goes directly to presenter.PriceList.

But, again, I am not sure.